# Extracting SRT/etc from original video to use when re-encoding to H.265

Tags: vlc, srt, h.265

I'm using VLC to playback my H.265 videos
Using Cyberlink PowerDirector to re-encode videos to H.265 from original H.264, saves a bunch of space and i'm the only one viewing the content so not an issue for media platforms.

Currently when running the re-encode the video will come out as expected, except the subtitles no longer exist. This software does have the ability to attach subs via SRT or what have you but I need to first extract the existing subs into a text file as the program doesn't allow that (to my knowledge), VLC apparently does?

Comment: After further research VLC does not allow extracting them. Only reading/disabling

Comment: Nevermind i figured out how to use the extract subtitles function that is indeed built into power director. Which i found zero documentation on prior to asking this question thus thought it wasn't a thing.

Answer (score 0):

PowerDirector does indeed have a built in function to extract subtitles from a video which can be accessed via the timeline when right clicking the video and selecting "Extract Subtitles/English" or whatever language.
This imports the existing data into a locally stored SRT directly in the built in subtitles editor page of the program.